# Checkboxes and radio button selected values not getting cleared using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

When I'm clicking on the cancel button I need to clear entered or selected values in controls (textboxes, checkboxes, and radio button).

Unfortunately the checkbox and radiobutton selected values not getting changed on cancel btn click and textbox values are cleared.

The controls are in div having id `divUser`. How can I clear the checkboxes selection and radio button?

```
$("#btnCancel").click(function () {          
    $('input, select,input:radio', $('#divUser')).val(''); 
});
```

Comment: If you are using HTML only for that, i suggest use <`input type="reset" />` it will reset everything without applying `jQuery` or anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#btnCancel").click(function () {          
    $('input', $('#divUser')).val(''); 
    $('select,input:radio', $('#divUser')).attr('checked', false); 
});
```

trick here is change checked attribute instead of value.

Answer (score 1):

To unselect or uncheck radio buttons and checkboxes you need to remove the `checked` attribute:

```
$("input:radio,input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#btnCancel").click(function ()
{
   $('input, select,input:radio,#divUser').val('');
});
```

Comment: @user2156088 and can u please tell me what that comment means.